# Trying to systematically remove elements from a list, but some elements are left out?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have tried to create a list of whole numbers under 1000 (aka, 0 to 999), then delete the numbers that don't comply with a certain rule [ex. must be divisible by 7 or 3]. After, I have find the sum of all these numbers. Below is the code I wrote to do so.

```
number_list = []

for x in range(1000):
number_list.append(x)

index = 0
element = number_list[index]

max = 1000
deleted = 0

while index < max - deleted:

    element = number_list[index]

    if element % 7 != 0 or element % 3 != 0:
        number_list.remove(element)
        deleted = deleted + 1

    index = index + 1

print(sum(number_list))
```

This runs without any issues, but it does not return the correct sum. **The correct sum is 214216, but this gives me 261832 instead, leading me to believe that more than 40 elements that should have been deleted, have not been deleted.**

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The list comprehension is probably the right way to go about it, but, in general, if you ever want to iterate through a list while deleting things, go backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension should be simpler for this problem. Anyway, I'll try to fix your implementation.

- The condition `element % 7 != 0 or element % 3 != 0` should be `and`
  instead of `or`.
- If a number is deleted in the loop iteration, `index` shouldn't move to the next, because the *next* element is at this `index` now.

In summary:

```
if element % 7 != 0 or element % 3 != 0:
    number_list.remove(element)
    deleted = deleted + 1

index = index + 1
```

should be:

```
if element % 7 != 0 and element % 3 != 0:
    number_list.remove(element)
    deleted = deleted + 1
else:
    index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it using list comprehensions:

```
number_list = [i for i in range(1000) if not i % 7 != 0 or not i % 3 != 0 ]
print sum(number_list) #Python2
```

Output:

```
214216
```

Comment: `not i % 3 != 0` -> `i % 3 == 0` Same for the one before it.

Comment: @Navith `not i % != 0` is the same as `i % 3 == 0`

Comment: I know, and it takes up fewer characters and is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

When you remove elements from the list: `number_list.remove(element)`, the meaning of the index changes so that on the next iteration, after incrementing `index`, `element = number_list[index]` now references a value other than the `index`-th item of *the original* `number_list`. Thus, some values in the original `number_list` are never checked.

The solution, in general, is to [not mutate a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/190597). Instead, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (or, for memory-efficiency, a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)) to build a new list:

```
In [107]: sum([i for i in range(1000) if (i % 7 == 0) or (i % 3 == 0)])
Out[107]: 214216
```

or, iterate over `index` *backwards*, counting from 999 down to 0, so that removing the `index`-th item will not affect the indexing of other items when using a smaller index.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is much simpler.

```
sum=0
for x in range(1000):
    if x % 7 == 0 or x % 3 == 0:
        sum=sum+x
print sum
```

Result:

```
214216
```